# mvc url.action returning null or url as get

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing

I am using mvc Url.Action as this

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Product", new { area = "Product", search = UrlParameter.Optional, categoryId = category.IdCategory })">
```

I have my routing as:-

```
public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
{
    context.MapRoute(
        "Product_default",
        "Product/{controller}/{action}/{id}/{categoryId}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Product", action = "Index", search = UrlParameter.Optional, categoryId = @"\d+" },
        namespaces: new[] { "IBuyFrontEnd.Areas.Product.Controllers" }
    );

}
```

I cannot get the url to map to this route. I am getting it as

However if i change the action to

```
@Url.Action("Index", "Product")
```

I get this as Url

```
http://localhost/iteric/?action=Index&controller=Product
```

I cannot figure the why so of this behavior. Just started using .net mvc. Please help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

Ok So figured out that to get Url.Action to generate the url requires the that action to be present in the controller, and also the parameters should be in place. So i just changed my controller action to

```
public ActionResult Index( int? categoryId,string search)
{
    return View();
}
```